# ASP.NET Core 2.2 Multiple constructors accepting all given argument types have been found in type 'MoviesController'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

tengo un problema que no termino de entender y no se como solucionar.

Estoy aprendiendo a usar ASP.NET Core con los tutoriales de Microsoft, mirando en otros sitios para aprender a globalizar e internacionalizar una aplicación, etc... y a veces me pierdo bastante...

Cuando ejecuto la web, me funciona sin problemas, pero cuando le doy al link para ir a otro método, me da este error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   InvalidOperationException: Multiple constructors accepting all given
>   argument types have been found in type
>   'MvcMovie.Controllers.MoviesController'. There should only be one
>   applicable constructor.
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.TryFindMatchingConstructor(Type
>   instanceType, Type[] argumentTypes, ref ConstructorInfo
>   matchingConstructor, ref Nullable[] parameterMap)

Parece ser que es un problema de controladores y tal, pero es que no termino de entender porqué.

Este es el controlador que parece fallar:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization;
using MvcMovie.Models;


namespace MvcMovie.Controllers
{
    public class MoviesController : Controller
 {
    private readonly IStringLocalizer<MoviesController> _localizer;

    public MoviesController(IStringLocalizer<MoviesController> localizer)
    {
        _localizer = localizer;
    }

    private readonly MvcMovieContext _context;

    public MoviesController(MvcMovieContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: Movies
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string movieGenre, string searchString)
    {
        //ViewData["controllerText"] = _localizer["Texto de ejemplo pasado desde el controlador."];

        // Use LINQ to get list of genres.
        IQueryable<string> genreQuery = from m in _context.Movie
                                        orderby m.Genre
                                        select m.Genre;

        var movies = from m in _context.Movie
                     select m;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(movieGenre))
        {
            movies = movies.Where(x => x.Genre == movieGenre);
        }

        var movieGenreVM = new MovieGenreViewModel
        {
            Genres = new SelectList(await genreQuery.Distinct().ToListAsync()),
            Movies = await movies.ToListAsync()
        };

        return View(movieGenreVM);
    }

    // GET: Movies/Details/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var movie = await _context.Movie
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        if (movie == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(movie);
    }

    // GET: Movies/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Movies/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Title,ReleaseDate,Genre,Price,Rating")] Movie movie)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(movie);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(movie);
    }

    // GET: Movies/Edit/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var movie = await _context.Movie.FindAsync(id);
        if (movie == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return View(movie);
    }

    // POST: Movies/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,Title,ReleaseDate,Genre,Price,Rating")] Movie movie)
    {
        if (id != movie.Id)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Update(movie);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!MovieExists(movie.Id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(movie);
    }

    // GET: Movies/Delete/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var movie = await _context.Movie
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        if (movie == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(movie);
    }

    // POST: Movies/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        var movie = await _context.Movie.FindAsync(id);
        _context.Movie.Remove(movie);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    private bool MovieExists(int id)
    {
        return _context.Movie.Any(e => e.Id == id);
    }

    public IActionResult SetLanguage(string culture, string returnUrl)
    {
        Response.Cookies.Append(
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
            new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1) 
    }
        );

        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
    }
   }
  }
```

A ver si me podéis dar alguna pista, por favor. Os pongo un acceso a mi git por si queréis echar un vistazo:

https://github.com/erniker/TrainingNETCore/tree/master/MvcMovie

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Entiendo que en este tipo de inyecciones no se puede tener varios constructores. Debes dejar solo uno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu Controlador, estás recibiendo mediante **Inyección de Dependencias** a través del Constructor los objetos `localizer` y `context`.

En estos casos en los que se realiza una Inyección de Dependencias, solo está permitido que definas un **único Constructor**. Esto es así, ya que si defines múltiples Constructores, no se podría determinar cual de ellos es el que debería **inicializar** la Clase controladora.

Debes definir **un solo Constructor** de la siguiente manera:

```
private readonly MvcMovieContext _context;
private readonly IStringLocalizer<MoviesController> _localizer;

public MoviesController(IStringLocalizer<MoviesController> localizer, MvcMovieContext context)
{
    _localizer = localizer;
    _context = context;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Rafael, esto que me dices lo había visto también por otro hilo de aquí, pero es que no sabia como aplicar la solution, ahora todo va genial :)

Comment: @JoséPabloMedinaGrande: Estupendo!. Recuerda siempre valorar las respuestas que te han ayudado a solucionar tu pregunta, con eso estarás colaborando con la buena salud de este sitio.